# I broke an End Gateway in creative Minecraft Pocket Edition

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was playing Pocket Edition in creative and I broke the portal block. I do not know where it went, so I have no cords. I need to know how to restore it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `/setblock` or `/fill` command to put an `end_portal_block` at the exact location